# specify GitHub's Package Repository in buildspec.yml

Tags: aws-codebuild, github-package-registry

I have an AWS CodeBuild process kicking off whenever I check code into master branch of my GitHub repo.  My codebase is a dotnet core serverless application.  I have a dependency on a private nuget package residing in GitHub Package Repository.  My CodeBuild process is failing when trying to find the package:

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package datastop.io.data-dictionary. 
No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

`datastop.io.data-dictionary` is a private nuget package residing in GitHub Package Repository, not in nuget.org.  It appears from the error message the CodeBuild process is attempting to find 'datastop.io.data-dictionary' in nuget.

Here's my current buildspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            dotnet: 2.1
        commands:
            - echo Entered the install phase...
            - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
            - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - echo Entered the pre_build phase...
            - dotnet restore
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Entered the build phase...
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - cd $FOLDER
            - dotnet lambda package --configuration release --framework netcoreapp2.1 -o ./$ZIPPED_APPLICATION
            - aws cloudformation package --template-file infrastructure.yml --s3-bucket $S3_DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET --output-template-file packaged-infrastructure.yml --region us-east-2
            - aws cloudformation deploy --template-file packaged-infrastructure.yml --stack-name $CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_NAME --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region us-east-2
```

The build process is failing while running `dotnet restore`.

I'm assuming I need to modify my buildspec.yml file somehow to let the build process know to look at the correct package repository (our private GitHub Package Repository).  How do I modify my buildspec.yml file to point to the appropriate GitHub Package Repository when trying to find `datastop.io.data-dictionary` package?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `nuget.config` file to your project, and add your GitHub repo to that config it will know where to look. From there it's a question of permissions, which is what I'm struggling with.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This was the issue for me. We created the nuget.config and had it configured right, but the file was in the wrong directory. We use docker and so we just moved it to the same directory as the docker file and that was it!